# Create pandas MultiIndex Dataframe without NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I feel like I'm missing something fundamentally here. I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(3)).T
df.columns = ['a.first', 'a.second', 'b']

#    a.first  a.second  b
# 0        0         1  2
```

What I would like to create is a MultiIndex DataFrame where I can use df.a, df.a.first and df.b. What I got so far is the str split method:

```py
a.columns = a.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
#        a            b
#    first  second  NaN
# 0      0       1    2
```

So obviously the NaN is a problem here, because to access value b, one would need to call `df.b[np.nan]`, which feels obviously wrong.

Starting from here, all the solutions that come to my mind start feeling like workaround where I iterate over the columns and try to replace the NaNs with empty strings. I imagine that there must be a much more straightforward way, as I guess that this is a pretty common problem, no?

**Edit:** The least ugly solution that came to mind so far is the following:

```py
def apply_multiindex(df, hier_sep='.'):
    depths = df.columns.str.split(hier_sep).map(len)
    add_hiers = max(depths)-depths
    df.columns = [column + hier_sep*add_hier[c]
                  for c, column in enumerate(df.columns)]
    df.columns = df.columns.str.split(hier_sep, expand=True)

apply_multiindex(a)
#        a          b
#    first  second  
# 0      0       1  2
```

I'm still looking forward to a more cleaner solution :)

Comment: Because your b do not contain `.`. So splitting with dot will result in 0 columns that's why nan appears. You can have b.first or somthing like that and it will work fine

Comment: So what do you want instead of `NaN`?

Comment: I  think this is the correct solution. The NaN is okay, but you could replace it by some other attribut of course.

Comment: @DanielMesejo, I would like to have '' instead of NaN. The problem with NaN is that to access `df.b`, I need to actually call `df.b[np.nan]`. This feels so obviously wrong that I expected some convenience function to handle this.

Comment: @PySeeker do you have by any chance a nice piece of code to replace the NaNs? Problem is that MultiIndex does not support fillna() at the moment, that's why I always end up in casting hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working `rename` with missing value, because `fillna` for `MultiIndex` is not implemented:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(range(3))], columns = ['a.first', 'a.second', 'b'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)

df = df.rename(columns = {np.nan:''})
print (df)
      a         b
  first second   
0     0      1  2
```